# Pros and cons of loading DirectX DLLs directly?

Tags: c++, directx, dll

I have been looking at the source code of various commercial games, and I have noticed that a lot of them load video card/input DLLs directly using LoadLibrary().

I wanted to mod one, but also make my own engine, so I was wondering what would be the benefits of loading DirectX 11 DLLs directly, as opposed to link the program with .libs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the DLLs are loaded using a .lib your game will fail to launch if the DLLs are missing.

Loading DLLs using `LoadLibrary` lets you display a friendlier message on failure and allows you implement a fallback system to a previous version of DirectX if the latest is unavailable.